# Question about affine span and symmetric matrices

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

$A$ and $B$ are real $n\times n$ matrices and $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}$ : $I+xA+yB$ is positive semidefinite matrix $\}$.

Prove that $\mathbb{R^2}= Aff(S)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.
Here $Aff(S)$ stands for affine span of $S$.
I have proved that if $\mathbb{R^2}= Aff(S)$ then $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.
I have problem with proving other direction. 
Any ideas would be helpful.

Since $S \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ then $Aff(S) \subset \mathbb{R^2}$. It is obvious since $\mathbb{R^2}$ is affine subspace. 
I am not sure how to prove other inclusion if it is known that matrices $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.

Comment: How did you prove that $A$ and $B$ must be symmetric for the other direction?

Comment: Well I do not know if It is correct but I took an element in $\mathbb{R^2}$ which is also element of affine span of $S$ so it must be affine combination of elements in S. For each element of $S$ we have that matrix $I+x_iA+y_iB$ is semi definite so it is symmetric. Symmetric matrix is equal to its transpose matrix. From there I have got that transpose of  $A$ is $A$ and the same for matrix $B$.

Comment: It can be correct. The main thing is that linear combinations of symmetric matrices are symmetric, and thus $A$ and $B$ can be expressed by several instances of $I+xA+yB$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's enough to show $(0,0),\ (x,0),\ (0,y)\in S$ for some nonzero $x, y$. 
Then find such an $x$ using the eigenvalues of $A$.